# How to bottom margin with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

#### How do I add bottom margin for my selection box?

I've already tried

```css
#Selection { margin-bottom:23px; }
```

But this does not work for me. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript or jQuery.

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrg59705/)

### Snippet Below :-

```js
var startX = 0,
  startY = 0,
  started = false;

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  startX = e.pageX;
  startY = e.pageY;
  started = true;
  $('#selection').css({
    'top': startY,
    'left': startX
  });
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (started) {

    $('#selection').css({
      'left': startX > e.pageX ? e.pageX : startX,
      'top': startY > e.pageY ? e.pageY : startY
    });

    $('#selection').css({
      'height': Math.abs(e.pageY - startY),
      'width': Math.abs(e.pageX - startX)
    });
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  $('#selection').css({
    'top': 0,
    'left': 0,
    'height': 0,
    'width': 0
  });
  started = false;
  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  background:url(http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/Windows-7-UI-and-Windows-Aero-for-Websites/win7-desktop-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:90%;
  top:0px;
}
#selection {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -ms-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -o-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
}
#bottom {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  text-align:center;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="selection"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
  <font size="+3" color="lime">don't want selection box here!</font>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you want selection box at ?

Comment: @DinoMyte i want it on inside the <div id="container">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How about this hack:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;

    -moz-transform: scale(1,0.90);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1,0.90);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,0.90);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(1,0.90);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2rvorgy/

## Or this hack:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2rvorgy/1/
Although with this solution, the `#Selection` is still draggable to the very bottom of the document, but it avoids it to be over the bottom-bar (`#bottom`) though.

Comment: please add second hack snippet.

Comment: It's the second code I added to the answer and the link below it's the jsFiddle example for it. http://jsfiddle.net/c2rvorgy/1/

Answer (score 2):

`#selection` is not giving you a `margin-bottom` because it is absolutely positioned, also there is no other elements underneath it for it to have a margin bottom.

Use this to illustrate with demo on bottom:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="selection">Hello</div>
   <div id="selection">Hello</div>
   <div id="selection">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#selection {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -ms-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -o-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**Applying Margins with JQuery & Vanilla JS**

If you want to apply a `margin-bottom` with jQuery you can add this to your script file, note that I changed its identifier from a ID to class to target multiples.

```
$(".selection").css("margin-bottom", "25px");
```

Here is the pure JavaScript equivelent of the above(I used ID for this):

```
document.getElementById("selection").style.marginBottom = "25px";
```

**Hiding the Bottom Element**

To remove that `#bottom` element you can simply increase your bottom distance to `-100px` since you're using `position:absolute` in order to hide it. Lets say you want to display it, you can then tie it to an event such as `mouseover`.

Here is a demo:

CSS:

```
#bottom {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  text-align:center;
  bottom:-100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#container").mouseover(function(){
    $("#bottom").animate({bottom: "0px"});
});

$("#container").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#bottom").animate({bottom: "-100px"});
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/NGEKZo?editors=001)

Comment: Don't use css because i don't want this add some javascript or jQuery to add bottom margin

Comment: I updated my pen, look at the bottom of the JS file to see how to apply margins with jQuery.

Comment: I added a jQuery and a vanilla JS way to apply this style as well.

Comment: if you just want to hide it you can give it an opacity of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't want the background picture be covered under `<div id="botton">`?

If the answer is yes, then you just move `background:url(http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/Windows-7-UI-and-Windows-Aero-for-Websites/win7-desktop-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;`

from `body` to `#selection`:

```
    #selection {
//move the picture here
         background:url(http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/Windows-7-UI-and-Windows-Aero-for-Websites/win7-desktop-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    //give the picture width and height otherwise you cant see the picture 
    //on the page because this <div> was 0px by 0px;
        width:100%;   
        height:100%;

      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
      -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
      -ms-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
      -o-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
      box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
    }
```

The reason you adjusted `#selection` didn't work is because the background picture is attached on the entire  of page. you have to nest that picture under `<div id="container">` or `<div id="selection">` depends on what effect you want to see.